# Logout redirect via page template without confirmation?

Tags: functions, errors, page-template, logout

I'm trying to redirect users when they visit my page template `template-logout.php`, but I keep getting the Wordpress "Do you really want to logout?" question despite wpnonce being generated. What am I doing wrong?

Here's an example of the type of URL being generated by my function below when I reach that WP confirmation page:

*https://localssl:8890/wp-login.php?action=logout&redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Flocalssl%3A8890&_wpnonce=752dc07192*

**CODE**

`template-logout.php`

```
<?php 
/**
 * Template name: Log Out
 */

get_header(); 

// Logic handled via functions.php

get_footer(); ?>
```

`functions.php`

```
// Redirects for template pages
add_filter('template_redirect', 'osu_redirect_on_logout');
function osu_redirect_on_logout() {
    if ( is_page_template( 'templates/template-logout.php' ) ) {
        $logout_url = wp_logout_url( home_url() );
        wp_safe_redirect( $logout_url ); // Logout and Redirect to homepage
        exit;
    }
}
```

### ** **EDIT** **

Answer below by Gabriel is the better way of doing this, I was getting muddled with the redirection side of things. To make sure this method redirects to the homepage, this was my final code:

```
// Redirect to homepage when using wp_logout();
add_action( 'wp_logout', 'osu_redirect_homepage_after_logout');
function osu_redirect_homepage_after_logout(){
    wp_redirect( home_url() );
    exit();
}

// Redirects for template pages
add_filter('template_redirect', 'osu_redirect_on_logout');
function osu_redirect_on_logout() {
    if ( is_page_template( 'templates/template-logout.php' ) ) {
        wp_logout();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to logout a user and redirect them back to the homepage, could you just use the `wp_logout()` function?

So instead of this:

```
if ( is_page_template( 'templates/template-logout.php' ) ) {
    $logout_url = wp_logout_url( home_url() );
    wp_safe_redirect( $logout_url ); // Logout and Redirect to homepage
    exit;
}
```

Your logic could just be:

```
if ( is_page_template( 'templates/template-logout.php' ) ) {
    wp_logout();
}
```

Comment: That's great, the only issue was the redirection to the homepage, but I added some code to make the default redirect for `wp_logout()` to the homepage via another function - I'll add it to the question above in case it's useful for others.